# FXCollections, Callback<E, Observable[]> extractor for Sets?

Tags: javafx, observable, extractor

I am aware of the factory method that takes an extractor as a parameter:

```
FXCollections.observableList(List<E> list, Callback<E, Observable[]> extractor)
```

Is there an equivalent for an `ObservableSet`?

If not, how can I achieve same/ similar functionality when I use an `ObservableSet` instead of an `ObservableList`?

Comment: I decided to use an ObservableList instead for now. First because trying to make it work using the ObservableSet is (currently) not worth the effort. Second, I agree to @fabian 's point of view, concerning modifying a Set's elements. For me its not an issue, but I agree, it smells a bit..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't. In fact, where `ListChangeListener.Change` has a [`wasUpdated()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#wasUpdated--), which returns `true` when the change is created because one of the properties specified in the extractor has changed, [`SetChangeListener.Change`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/SetChangeListener.Change.html) has no such method.

If your set contains elements of type `S`, which has a property of type `Property<T>`, call it `someProperty()`, in which you are interested, you can do

```
ChangeListener<T> listener = (obs, oldValue, newValue) -> { /* some code */ };

ObservableSet<S> set = FXCollections.observableSet();
set.addListener((Change<? extends S> c) -> {
    if (c.wasAdded()) {
        c.getElementAdded().someProperty().addListener(listener);
    }
    if (c.wasRemoved()) {
        c.getElementRemoved().someProperty().removeListener(listener);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`SetChangeListener.Change`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/SetChangeListener.Change.html) lacks a *Update* change type (there are only *Add* / *Remove* changes).

Therefore you cannot achieve this kind of behavior with a `ObservableSet`, simply because it's not part of the `ObservableSet` interface.

You'd need to define your own interface to achieve this behavior.

Note that modifying `Set` elements is often a bad idea, since it can mess up the way the data is stored. If the modification e.g. changes the hashCode, you won't get the correct results, if you modify an element of a `HashSet`